# Cannot create a new app?

Tags: facebook

I'm not able to create a new app, I followed all the instructions on creating new apps but it did not work for me.

> Start by visiting the Developer App. If you haven't created an
>   application before you will be prompted to add the Developer
>   Application.

So when I click Developers app nothing happens; It only take me or load to my page. Nothing promoted me to add the developers application, even though the instruction says

> you will be prompted to add the Developer Application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, seems that you need to log in using a facebook account of a real user, not a page you created for a business. Only real users can create apps.